# Maya UI text box act like keyable text box in Maya

Tags: python, user-interface, maya, keyframe

I want my text box to become red and pink when some attribute has kes, should I make a script job on frame change and query each frame for keyframes? is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. Should your text change only if a special attribute has a keyframe on the current frame or does it have to change if the attribute has a predefined value like 5 or 10? Do you need it in batch too?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you for you time, I kind of figure it out myself, sorry I am pretty new in this :)

Answer (score 0):

[I was looking for something like this, thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBJWb.jpg)